# Reference request for Morse theory with complex valued functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, morse-theory

I was just wondering if there is a version of Morse theory by considering maps from $f: M \to \mathbb{C}$ where $M$ is a complex manifold and $f^{\prime \prime }(z) \neq 0 $ whenever $f^{\prime}(z)=0$.

After searching for some time, I found that functions to a circle have been studied but I could not find anything for a complex valued function. Does anyone know of any references or does this simplify to Morse theory in the real case? Thank you.

Comment: There's definitely sources for this, but some basic things to note (why it is probably less rich) is that on compact complex manifolds there are no non-constant holomorphic functions and there is a unique (up to isomorphism) symmetric $\Bbb C$ bilinear form on $\Bbb C$ (there is no useful notion of index of a critical point).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct holomorphic analogue of Morse functions on compact complex manifolds is a [Lefschetz pencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_pencil) (see also and references therein); see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152373/trying-to-understand-lefschetz-pencils). A LP is a holomorphic map $f: M\to {\mathbb C} P^1$, which has only Morse critical points. They are well-studied.

Edit (thanks to Nicolas Hemelsoet): 1. See also ["The topology of complex projective varieties after S. Lefschetz"](http://www.dmi.unict.it/~frusso/DMI/Seminari_2015_files/Lamotke%20Topology%20of%20complex%20algebraic%20Varieties.pdf), by Klaus Lamotke.

2. One can also consider holomorphic maps to Riemann surfaces of higher genus ($\ge 1$), but they do not always exist (but when they do exist, they become quite useful). Maybe one should regard them as holomorphic analogues of circle-valued Morse functions.

Comment: +1, I would add that a great reference about it is Klaus Lamotke, "The topology of complex projective varieties after S. Lefschetz".